# HighCharts Heatmap with bubbles and Arrows

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a Highcharts Heatmap with bubbles and Arrows between them as data-series that looks like: 
[image]

If I add one Arrow more, a black bar appears:
[image]

Code of an Arrow:

```
   var arrow =  {
      type: 'scatter',
      enableMouseTracking: false,
      name: 'Arrow',
      lineWidth: 1.5,
      lineColor: 'rgba(117,117,117,1)',
      dashStyle: 'dash',
      marker: {
        enabled: false
      },
      data: [[startX,startY],[endX,endY]],
      endMarker: 'url(#arrow)',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false,
      }
    }
```

Is this a Highcharts bug or I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please create a live demo in JSFiddle or provide another way to recreate the problem.

Comment: It was my mistake, I had the same arrow with the same coordinates twice..